# Is it possible to have multiple objects in a business layer for 3-tier architecture

Tags: architecture, 3-tier

I'm working on a school project and just wondering if it is possible to have 2 business objects linking to each other to 1 presentation layer.
Attached an example of what I'm trying to say here:

[3-tier Architecture Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMdic.png)

I have Purchase Process and Items Details Process linked up in Business Layer because I do need some modules in the purchase process to be able to run in items details and get the details from the API. 
However, I'd only like to have 1 Output in the Presentation Layer.

Any idea if this works in a 3-tier architecture system or am I not supposed to link up my 2 objects in the Business Layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the principal you are looking for is the separation of concerns.

With the available context what I can say is there are no issues couple two functions of the business layer into one presentation layer function if that's your business requirement but the only problem is it will be highly coupled and would be troublesome to operate independently of each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
However, some parts of one business layer require calling the module from the other business layer. 
Is it better to combine both into one business layer then?

Comment: That has to be decided after looking at the requirements and further expansion.

Comment: Since you are new to StackOverflow, If you feel the answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark or upvote the answer.